# Page-change event not working in ng2-bootstrap

Tags: pagination, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the pagination in my angular2 app with the ng2-bootrap. am following http://valor-software.github.io/ng2-bootstrap/#pagination

my **app.html**

```
<div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
        <pagination [totalItems]="bigTotalItems" (page-changed)="pageChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="bigCurrentPage" [maxSize]="maxSize"
        class="pagination-sm" [boundaryLinks]="true"></pagination>
    </div>
</div>
```

my component

```
import { Component, View, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
import { PAGINATION_COMPONENTS } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

// webpack html imports
@View({
    templateUrl: '/scripts/src/components/demo/demo.html',
    directives: [PAGINATION_COMPONENTS, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Component({
    selector: 'tabs-demo',
})
export class DemoComponent {
    private totalItems: number = 64;
    private currentPage: number = 4;

    private maxSize: number = 5;
    private bigTotalItems: number = 175;
    private bigCurrentPage: number = 1;

    private setPage(pageNo: number): void {
        this.currentPage = pageNo;
    };

    private pageChanged(event: any): void {
        console.log('Page changed to: ' + event.page);
        console.log('Number items per page: ' + event.itemsPerPage);
    };
}
```

but when i change the pagination page its not triggering the pagechanged event.
Please correct me to work it properly.

Comment: The Output is called `pageChanged`, not `page-changed`.

Comment: ohh its work for me thanks

Comment: You could also use canonical syntax which is `on-page-changed="pageChanged($event)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Output is called pageChanged, not page-changed